# Do the WCF timeouts on server side bindings have any relevance?

Tags: wcf, timeout

I host a WCF Service on IIS and have the following binding in web.config:

```
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="transactionalBinding" 
                 transactionFlow = "true" 
                 sendTimeout     = "00:00:01" 
                 receiveTimeout  = "00:00:01" 
                 openTimeout     = "00:00:01" 
                 closeTimeout    = "00:00:01">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

In my service method I sleep for 10 seconds. I do not get a timeout exception when calling my service method from a client.

Is there any meaning in defining timeouts in server side bindings?

Comment: Please don't edit your question so as to possibly invalidate any pre-existing answers.   Consider posting that as a _new_ question.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not get a timeout exception when calling my service method from a client.

---

**TL;DR:** because WCF timeouts by default are **one minute** so naturally a server operation that only takes 10 seconds isn't going to timeout.  The timeouts you have specified on the server would only affect transmission not execution of your method. (you aren't calling anything else)

---

You are specifying the timeouts in the **server** config.  What you **need to do** is specify the timeouts in the **client's** config file, specifically **SendTimeout**.  Essentially whatever end is making the call, needs to specify the operation timeout.  Probably not relevant in your case but if your "server" in turn made another WCF call to another service, you would want your own timeout there too.

MSDN:

> **SendTimeout** – used to initialize the `OperationTimeout`, which governs the whole process of sending a message, including receiving a reply message for a request/reply service operation. This timeout also applies when sending reply messages from a callback contract method.

Generally, WCF client and server configs should match one another and unless you are using **Add Service Reference/Refresh Service Reference** each time the server contracts and/or config change, the client won't know about it.  By the way, avoid the latter because it duplicates your model and can lead to runtime errors if they are out of sync.  Not to mention service contracts can get out of sync.

### A passing thought

And this brings up one of the problems of WCF configuration via config files, they are subject to runtime errors impossible to find at compile time.

A better practice is to do away with config files completely and do programatic configuration via a common assembly that both your client and server use.  Specify bindings in code along with your timeouts.

That way both server and client are always in sync with regards to WCF configuration.

With both client and server agreeing on timeouts would have addressed some issues.

### Tell me more

- *[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0809101/WCF-the-Manual-Way%E2%80%A6-the-Right-Way)*

Comment: Why should I define the timeouts server side? They seem not to have any effect.

Comment: @Alex I said **client**-side not server-side.  WCF timeouts by default are one minute so naturally a server operation that only takes 10 seconds isn't going to timeout.

Comment: So there is no reason to define WCF timeouts server side.

Comment: @Alex Not at all.  _"[ReceiveTimeout – used by the Service Framework Layer to initialize the session-idle timeout which controls how long a session can be idle before timing out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding)"_.  In other words, how long before the server disconnects an idle WCF client.  Typically happens if you have a client proxy laying about

Comment: So receiveTimeout on server side has an effect only on ServiceContracts with sessions (<ServiceContract(SessionMode:=SessionMode.Required)>)?
If there is no session, then receiveTimeout on server side has no effect?

Comment: @Alex No, it's just one scenario.  `ReceiveTimeout` also applies to the underlying _channel_ (the actual connection, whether it is TCP; http; pipes etc) which is used irrespective of whether your service is `PerCall` or not. You could by way of the same client proxy, make several calls in series to a server and it would be the same underlying channel each time.  Read about the former here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: ...and I meant to say, if your client waited too long between calls you might get a timeout